# andling table data with comboboxes and textboxes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium . I have a web page to test with lots of `text boxes` and `combo box`. When `sumbit` button is pressed data ie already entered in `texboxes` got inserted and is displayed in a table below it .

How I fetch each data from `textbox` and `combobox` and compare it with table data.

For example `commbobox1` data is 'IT Asset',`combobox2` data is 'Monitor' ,combox 3 data is 'Acer Monitor'.

After insert, the table below is displayed with data mentioned like this

**Sl.NO    |     Asset Details**

1  |         ITAsset/Monitor/Acer

If we insert again it comes to table below with serial no 2.

Kindly ignore if any mistake.

I am using Java with selenium webdriver and data is passed from excel

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is very much unclear as with respect to what you are trying to verify as in each combo box value with the text in table or the whole value combined from 3 combo boxes. Still you can use below code to handle web tables dynamically when number of rows and columns are unknown before run-time:

```
//To locate table.
  WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("**table-locator**/tbody"));

//To locate rows of table.
 List<WebElement> rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

//To calculate no of rows In table.
  int rows_count = rows_table.size();

  //Loop will execute till the last row of table.
  for (int row=0; row<rows_count; row++){

//To locate columns(cells) of that specific row.
   List<WebElement> Columns_row =     rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

//To calculate no of columns(cells) In that specific row.
   int columns_count = Columns_row.size();
   System.out.println("Number of cells In Row "+row+" are "+columns_count);

  //Loop will execute till the last cell of that specific row.
   for (int column=0; column<columns_count; column++){
   //To retrieve text from that specific cell.
   String celtext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
    System.out.println("Cell Value Of row number "+row+" and column number "+column+" Is "+celtext);
```